# How to speed up my SUPER SLOW search script

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

**UPDATE (06/21/22): See my updated script below, which utilizes some of the answer.**

I am building a script to search for `$name` through a large batch of CSV files. These files can be as big as 67,000 KB. This is my script that I use to search the files:

**Powershell Script**

Essentially, I use `Import-Csv`. I change a few things depending on the file name, however. For example, some files don't have headers, or they may use a different delimiter. Then I store all the matches in `$results` and then return that variable. This  is all put in a function called `CSVSearch` for ease of running.

```
#create function called CSV Search
function CSVSearch{
    #prompt
    $name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input name'

    #set path to root folder
    $path = 'Path\to\root\folder\'

    #get the file path for each CSV file in root folder
    $files = Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

    #count files in $files
    $filesCount = $files.Count

    #create empty array, $results
    $results= @()

    #count for write-progress
    $i = 0

      foreach($file in $files){
       
        Write-Progress -Activity "Searching files: $i out of $filesCount searched. $resultsCount match(es) found" -PercentComplete (($i/$files.Count)*100)
        #import method changes depending on CSV file name found in $file (headers, delimiters). 
        if($file -match 'File1*'){$results += Import-Csv $file -Header A, Name, C, D -Delimiter '|' | Select-Object *,@{Name='FileName';Expression={$file}} | Where-Object { $_.'Name' -match $name}}
        if($file -match 'File2*'){$results += Import-Csv $file -Header A, B, Name  -Delimiter '|' | Select-Object *,@{Name='FileName';Expression={$file}} | Where-Object { $_.'Name' -match $name}}
        if($file -match 'File3*'){$results += Import-Csv $file | Select-Object *,@{Name='FileName';Expression={$file}} | Where-Object { $_.'Name' -match $name}}
        if($file -match 'File4*'){$results += Import-Csv $file | Select-Object *,@{Name='FileName';Expression={$file}} | Where-Object { $_.'Name' -match $name}}
        $i++
        $resultsCount = $results.Count
    
    }

    #if the loop ends and $results array is empty, return "No matches."
    if(!$results){Write-Host 'No matches found.' -ForegroundColor Yellow}
    #return results stored in $results variable
    else{$results 
    Write-Host $resultsCount 'matches found.' -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Progress -Activity "Completed" -Completed}

}

CSVSearch
```

Below are what the CSV files look like. Obviously, the amount of the data below is not going to equate to the *actual* size of the files. But below is the basic structure:

**CSV files**

```
File1.csv
1|Moonknight|QWEPP|L
2|Star Wars|QWEPP|T
3|Toy Story|QWEPP|U
```

```
File2.csv
JKLH|1|Moonknight
ASDF|2|Star Wars
QWER|3|Toy Story
```

```
File3.csv
1,Moonknight,AA,DDD
2,Star Wars,BB,CCC
3,Toy Story,CC,EEE
```

```
File4.csv
1,Moonknight,QWE
2,Star Wars,QWE
3,Toy Story,QWE
```

The script works great. Here is an example of the output I would receive if `$name = Moonknight`:

**Example of results**

```
A : 1
Name : Moonknight
C: QWE
FileName: Path\to\root\folder\File4.csv

A : 1
Name : Moonknight
B : AA
C : DDD
FileName: Path\to\root\folder\File3.csv

A : JKLH
B : 1
Name : Moonknight
FileName: Path\to\root\folder\File2.csv

A : 1
Name : Moonknight
C : QWEPP
D : L
FileName: Path\to\root\folder\File1.csv

4 matches found.
```

However, it is very slow, and I have a lot of files to search through. Any ideas on how to speed my script up?

Edit: I must mention. I tried importing the data into a hash table and then searching the hash table, but that was *much* slower.

**UPDATED SCRIPT - My Solution (06/21/22):**

This update utilizes some of Santiago's script below. I was having a hard time decoding everything he did, as I am new to PowerShell. So I sort of jerry rigged my own solution, that used a lot of his script/ideas.

The one thing that made a huge difference was outputting `$results[$i]` which returns the most recent match as the script is running. Probably not the most efficient way to do it, but it works for what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

```
function CSVSearch{
[cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Name
    )

$files = Get-ChildItem 'Path\to\root\folder\' -Filter *.csv -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}

$results = @()
$i = 0

foreach($file in $files){
if($file -like '*File1*'){$results += Import-Csv $file -Header A, Name, C, D -Delimiter '|' | Where-Object { $_.'Name' -match $Name} | Select-Object *,@{Name='FileName';Expression={$file}}}
if($file -like' *File2*'){$results += Import-Csv $file -Header A, B, Name  -Delimiter '|' | Where-Object { $_.'Name' -match $Name} | Select-Object *,@{Name='FileName';Expression={$file}}} 
if($file -like '*File3*'){$results += Import-Csv $file | Where-Object { $_.'Name' -match $Name} | Select-Object *,@{Name='FileName';Expression={$file}}}
if($file -like '*File4*'){$results += Import-Csv $file | Where-Object { $_.'Name' -match $Name} | Select-Object *,@{Name='FileName';Expression={$file}}}

$results[$i]
$i++
}

if(-not $results) {
        Write-Host 'No matches found.' -ForegroundColor Yellow
        return 
    }
        
    Write-Host "$($results.Count) matches found." -ForegroundColor Green

    }
```

Comment: For starters, filter before reconstructing (`Where-Object` should be before `Select-Object`)

Comment: Can you post your attempt at using hashtables? You might be using it wrong if it gets _slower_ as a result :)

Comment: FYI: Was merging 115 csv files into a single csv, took nearly 10 minutes.  Between switching to inline C# and optimizing the reading of the files, got it down to around one minute and 20 seconds.  Switching to inline C# alone was cutting the time to one third what it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this one a try, it should be a bit faster. `Select-Object` has to reconstruct your object, if you use it before filtering, you're actually recreating your entire CSV, you want to filter first (`Where-Object` / `.Where`) before reconstructing it.

[`.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#where) should be a faster than `Where-Object` here, the caveat is that the intrinsic method requires that the collections already exists in memory, there is no pipeline processing and no streaming.

`Write-Progress` will only slow down your script, better remove it.

Lastly, you can use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2) to avoid having multiple `if` conditions.

```
function CSVSearch {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Name,

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $Path = 'Path\to\root\folder\'
    )

    $param = @{
        File1 = @{ Header = 'A', 'Name', 'C', 'D'; Delimiter = '|' }
        File2 = @{ Header = 'A', 'B', 'Name' ; Delimiter = '|' }
        File3 = @{}; File4 = @{} # File3 & 4 should have headers ?
    }
    $results = foreach($file in Get-ChildItem . -Filter file*.csv) {
        $thisparam = $param[$file.BaseName]
        $thisparam['LiteralPath'] = $file.FullName
        (Import-Csv @thisparam).where{ $_.Name -match $name } |
            Select-Object *, @{Name='FileName';Expression={$file}}
    }

    if(-not $results) {
        Write-Host 'No matches found.' -ForegroundColor Yellow
        return 
    }
        
    Write-Host "$($results.Count) matches found." -ForegroundColor Green
    $results
}

CSVSearch -Name Moonknight
```

If you want the function to *stream* results as they're found, you can use a [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2#filters), this is a very efficient filtering technique, certainly faster than `Where-Object`:

```
function CSVSearch {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Name,

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $Path = 'Path\to\root\folder\'
    )

    begin {
        $param = @{
            File1 = @{ Header = 'A', 'Name', 'C', 'D'; Delimiter = '|' }
            File2 = @{ Header = 'A', 'B', 'Name' ; Delimiter = '|' }
            File3 = @{}; File4 = @{} # File3 & 4 should have headers ?
        }
        $counter = [ref] 0
        filter myFilter {
            if($_.Name -match $name) {
                $counter.Value++
                $_ | Select-Object *, @{N='FileName';E={$file}}
            }
        }
    }
    process {
        foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.csv) {
            $thisparam = $param[$file.BaseName]
            $thisparam['LiteralPath'] = $file.FullName
            Import-Csv @thisparam | myFilter
        }
    }
    end {
        if(-not $counter.Value) {
            Write-Host 'No matches found.' -ForegroundColor Yellow
            return 
        }
        Write-Host "$($counter.Value) matches found." -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of having multiple conditions for checking if the file base name is X or it is Y you can use a hashtable that holds the reference for the logic that has to be used for X and Y (this are the keys of the hashtable / the file BaseName). Since the logic is already there you can simply add to the hashtable the file's absolute path to read it and then use splatting. But I it is not easy to understand if you're new to powershell. @Crimp